# Traer información de varias tablas en una sola consulta SQL

Tags: sql

estoy aprendiendo SQL y estoy entrampado en cómo resolver lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pudiesen ayudar lo agradecería mucho. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Si estás haciendo esos ejercicios, ya deberías de haber leído acerca de los JOIN.

Comment: Gracias Luis, estuve dándole vuelta a los join para ver la solución hasta que me resultó.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Resultado final:

```
SELECT (AL.RUN||'-'||AL.DV) AS RunAlumno,(AL.NOMBRE||' '||AL.APELLIDO) AS NombreAlumno,(PROF.NOMBRE||' '||PROF.APELLIDO) AS NombreProfesor, SALA.NOMBRE AS SALA, CLASE.NOMBRE AS CLASE
FROM ALUMNO AL
JOIN clase_alumno CLAS_ALU
ON AL.ID=CLAS_ALU.ID_ALUMNO
JOIN PROFESOR PROF
ON PROF.ID=CLAS_ALU.ID_PROFESOR
JOIN SALA
ON SALA.ID=CLAS_ALU.ID_SALA
JOIN CLASE
ON CLASE.ID=CLAS_ALU.ID_CLASE
WHERE AL.EDAD>20
ORDER BY AL.NOMBRE
;
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).